Loop through a folder with .txt files and merge with a different file R
I want to loop through a folder that contains 250 .txt files and merge them with a single .txt file outside of this folder based on a common id column. Each file in the folder has over 6 million rows and is approximately 1GB on disk, so creating a list with them and reading them all at once is not feasible. The other_dataset is much smaller and is about 2000 rows of all unique values in the id column (no duplicates in this column.)
user_1 through user_250 are the of 250 files in a folder. other_dataset is the other .txt file I would like to merge with.
Sample data (with reduced columns) is included below:
user_1<- structure(list(ID2 = c(3481890, 3500406, 3507786, 3507978, 3512641, 3528872, 3546395, 3546395, 3572638, 3578447, 3581236, 3581236, 3581236, 3581236, 3599403, 3602306, 3603380, 3604665, 3612597, 3623200, 3623200), country = c("India", "India", "India", "Israel", "India", "India", "India", "India", "Belgium", "Israel", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "United States", 
"India", "Bulgaria", "India", "India"), id = c(197273, 197273, 
197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 
197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 197273, 
197273, 197273, 197273)), row.names = 2000000:2000020, class = "data.frame")
.
.
.
user_250<- structure(list(ID2 = c(1707253, 3039610, 3243469, 1613433, 
1871123, 1925738, 4313027, 1889109, 4554686, 1090264, 2848825, 
1194603, 1489041, 1489041, 1955845, 3401637, 2134398, 2216639, 
2216639, 2007909, 2311831), country = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "Philippines", "United States", "India", "Chile", 
"Bahrain", "Ethiopia", "Romania", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Spain", "Spain", "United Kingdom", "United States", 
"United States", "", "Australia"), id = c(92782473, 92782473, 
92782473, 92782474, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 92782477, 
92782479, 92782479, 92782480, 92782481, 92782481, 92782481, 92782481, 
92782486, 92782487, 92782487, 92782488, 92782488)), row.names = 6000500:6000520, class = "data.frame")

The following is the dataset I would like to merge the above data with.
other_dataset<- structure(list(id = c(197273, 92782473, 
197272, 197274, 197275, 197276, 197277, 708823, 708824, 708825, 92782487, 92782488, 92782489, 2782479, 92782475, 92782483, 92782481, 708822, 708824, 
708835), year = c(1951, 1951L, 1951, 1951, 1951, 
1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 
1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951, 1951)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

While there are similar questions such as This question as my question includes a large number of files (250) versus the 5 files included in this question. I also would like to create a loop to merge the 250.txt inside this folder with the single .txt file outside of this folder.
While I could make a list with the following method, due to the very large size of each of the 250 .txt files I would rather not do that as it takes a very long time. Is there a way to do an inner_join with the other_dataset one by one in a loop and only keep the relevant rows (matching ids)?
my_files <- lapply(Sys.glob("/Users/myname/user_positions/user_*.txt"), read.delim)


(The example data might be made more relevant by including some rows in other_dataset which correspond to some of the user_1 or user_250 data.

Thank you, I just edited the rows in the id column of the other_dataset  to include some rows from both user_1 and user_250 .

Maybe something like this? [EDIT: changed from csv to txt]
library(dplyr)

# save files to temp directory, as example
# These have one unneeded column -- imagine it's lots
td <- tempdir()
readr::write_tsv(user_1 |> mutate(unneeded_col = 1), file.path(td, "user_001.txt"))
readr::write_tsv(user_250 |> mutate(unneeded_col = 1), file.path(td, "user_250.txt"))

# get file names & load into named list
my_files <- list.files(td, pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

# function to read file and just keep certain columns
read_and_pare <- \(x) {
  x |> 
    read_delim() |>
    select(ID2, country, id)
}
# read data files into list, stack into one table, join to other table
purrr::map(my_files, read_and_pare) |>
  setNames(my_files) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "user_file") |>
  left_join(other_dataset,
            join_by(id == id))


would write.CSV work for my .txt files?

Same dif. I forgot yours were saved as txt vs csv. Replace read.csv with whatever code you're using to load your data. The write.csv part is just to artificially create some files to load.

I ran the code and I got the following error: Error in `inner_join()`: ! Join columns in `x` must be present in the data. ✖ Problem with `id`. Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I tried again, did not get the error but I am facing an issue of the code taking a long time and still not executing. Maybe it has been 30 minutes and it has not completed. The files are very large. So I think this method will not work. I updated the question to mention the size of the files.

How big are the txt files? "very large" is vague. If it's still very slow if you just do the map(my_files, read.delim) step, use a faster load function, like data.table::fread. The join might be slow if the same id values appear more than once in each table, as that will multiply the number of rows. In that case can you add any keys or remove unnecessary columns, or use a faster package like data.table or collapse or duckdb or arrow? The last two allow calcs on larger-than-RAM data, too.

Sorry about the vague information. The files inside the folder are approximately 1GB each with about 6 million rows each. I will edit the post to reflect this information. What is the best way to remove unnecessary columns from all the files before the merge? I am not good with working with files in a folder I know how to do things with one file at a time. The other_dataset has about 2000 rows and is has unique (not repeated values) in the id column.

I've edited to show an example where map now calls a function that both reads a file and only keeps a few columns that we want.
